# Почему я не могу убрать подчеркивание текста?

Tags: html, css

У меня прописано свойство text-decoration: underline; для всех элементов, которые находятся в div. Но прописав text-decoration: none; для одной из надписей, я все равно не могу избавиться от подчеркивания. В чем тут дело?

```css
.one {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: purple;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="one">Hello, world!</span>
  <br>
  <span class="two">Hello!</span>  
</div>
```

Comment: Не знаю почему, но если прописать display:inline-block то подчёркивание пропадает

Comment: @andreymal, там как-то все в спецификации накручено с этим

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как указано в [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration)

> Украшения текста отрисовываются вокруг дочерних элементов. Это значит, что если у элемента установлено свойство `text-decoration`, то дочерний элемент не может удалить его для себя.

<sub>перевод ответа [@xpy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36134860/2881286)</sub>

---

В [спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-4/#line-decoration) указано, что при применении данного свойства к элементу, оно будет распространено на все внутренние [in flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#in-flow) элементы (то есть на элементы, у которых не указан `float`, либо абсолютное позиционирование).

Так же есть уточнение

> декорация текста не распространяется на любые вложенные [out of flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#out-of-flow) элементы, ни на вложенные атомарные inline-level элементы, такие как `inline-block` и `inline-table`.

```css
.one {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div {
  width: 50%;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: purple;
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="one">Hello, world!</span>
  <br>
  <span class="two">Hello!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Буду знать, большое спасибо) Однако, свойство крайне неудобное в этом плане

Comment: @Eva, в общем там довольно запутанно получилось. Оно в принципе норм, если нет вложенных элементов, либо для вложенных нужно добавить, а не заменить. То есть, если ты у контейнера укажешь underline, а у дочернего = overline - то покажутся две линии